# what is V_VT and what does it return?

Tags: c++, active-directory, variant

Am working in Active Directory and i get to know that V_VT is used to get the type of the variant but when i used it and print it it shows 3 and what exactly does that mean? where can i fnd the documentation about it?

```
VARIANT var;
    VariantInit(&var);
    hr = pUsr->Get(CComBSTR("userAccountControl"), &var);
 if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        std::cout << V_VT(&var) << std::endl;
        VariantClear(&var);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it does much https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3b9f7b07-b3fd-404e-ba5d-8ff44c285d10/what-do-the-vvt-and-vunknown-macros-do?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: It is an accessor macro for the `vt` member of a `VARIANT` (or derivation thereof). There are accessor macros for *every* variant member. Ex: `V_BSTR` can be used to access `bstrVal`, `V_I4` access `lVal`, etc. Old-school COM programmers used these during the heyday when frankly you didn't know WTF MS was going to call a variant member. And yes, some of us still do use them (it's easy to tell which COM code I wrote at work vs. everyone else: They use `var.bstrVal`, I use `V_BSTR(&var)` by habit.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not be using VT_V at all (macros are not typesafe)
V_VT(x) provides (as documentation states) a "convenient shorthand" to access VARIANT fields. E.g.`V_VT(&vtXmlSource) = VT_UNKNOWN;` is equivalent to
`vtXmlSource.vt = VT_UNKNOWN;`

BSTR's are wide character strings (with different allocator/deallocator), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/automat/bstr. But you can use them to construct std::wstring from them.

Since you use ATL::CComBSTR, also consider using ATL::CComVariant to avoid memory leaks (manually calling ::VariantClear).

```
#include <cassert>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    ATL::CComVariant var{ L"hello world!" };
    assert(var.vt == VT_BSTR);

    ATL::CComBSTR bstr{ var.bstrVal };
    std::wstring str{ var.bstrVal };

    std::wcout << bstr.m_str << "\n";
    std::wcout << str << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: my question was whats the pupose of V_VT what does it return

Comment: V_VT  provides a "convenient shorthand" to access VARIANT fields. E.g.
`V_VT(&vtXmlSource) = VT_UNKNOWN;` is equivalent to 
`vtXmlSource.vt = VT_UNKNOWN;` . And should IMO not even exist, the assignment is much more clear. `V_VT(&var)` would be the same as outputting `var.vt`; My rule of thumb in C++, don't use macros unless there is no alternative.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yup, `vtXmlSource.vt = VT_UNKNOWN;` would've been very straightforward.

Comment: @JasonLiam Indeed, Sigh... the woes of the "convenience" macro. This question alone is a good proof, just write C++ code (functions/function templates). Macros usually only confuse other people.